# Convert Unicode char code to char on Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a list of Unicode character codes I need to convert into chars on python 2.7.

```
U+0021
U+0022
U+0023
.......
U+0024
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will replace all `U+nnnn` sequences with the corresponding Unicode character:

```
import re

s = u'''\
U+0021
U+0022
U+0023
.......
U+0024
'''

s = re.sub(ur'U\+([0-9A-F]{4})',lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)

print(s)
```

Output:

```
!
"
#
.......
$
```

Explanation:

- `unichr` gives the character of a codepoint, e.g. `unichr(0x21) == u'!'`.
- `int('0021',16)` converts a hexadecimal string to an integer.
- `lambda(m): expression` is an anonymous function that receives the regex match.
  It defines a function equivalent to `def func(m): return expression` but inline.
- `re.sub` matches a pattern and sends each match to a function that returns the replacement.  In this case, the pattern is `U+hhhh` where h is a hexadecimal digit, and the replacement function converts the hexadecimal digit string into a Unicode character.

Comment: yeah, I thought there should be something simpler( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone using Python 3 and above wonders, how to do this effectively, I'll leave this post here for reference, since I didn't realize the author was asking about Python 2.7...

Just use the built-in python function `chr()`:

```
char = chr(0x2474)
print(char)
```

Output:

```
⑴
```

Remember that the four digits in Unicode codenames `U+WXYZ` stand for a hexadecimal number `WXYZ`, which in python should be written as `0xWXYZ`.

Answer (score 0):

The code written below will take every Unicode string and will convert into the string.

```
for I in list:
    print(I.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
a = 'U+aaa'
a.encode('ascii','ignore')
'aaa'
```

This will convert for unicode to Ascii which i think is what you want.

Comment: This return a `str` in python 2 but return a `byte` in python3